# Integrating native UI in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am using the native Android `ProgressBar` in react native but something wrong happened. This is my `ProgressBarViewManager` code:

```
public class ProgressBarViewManager extends 
SimpleViewManager<ProgressBar> {

public static final String REACT_CLASS = "ProgressBar";

@Override
public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
protected ProgressBar createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new ProgressBar(reactContext);
}

@ReactProp(name = "progress", defaultInt = 0)
public void setProgress(ProgressBar view, int progress) {
    view.setProgress(progress);
}

@ReactProp(name = "indeterminate", defaultBoolean = false)
public void setIndeterminate(ProgressBar view, boolean indeterminate) {
    view.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
}
}
```

This is my ProgressBarPackage code

```
public class ProgressBarPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.<ViewManager>singletonList(
            new ProgressBarViewManager()
    );
}
}
```

I also added **new ProgressBarPackage()** in `MainApplication.java` but after running it is giving error:

```
**Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/user/React-native-Projects/AndroidComponentIntegeration/android/app/src/main/java/com/androidcomponentintegeration/ProgressBarPackage.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ReactPackage](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactPackage.java) class no longer (as of [this change](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ce6fb337a146e6f261f2afb564aa19363774a7a8), included in React Native 0.47) defines a `createJSModules` method, and so you no longer need to provide an implementation of it. Simply remove that method (including its @Override annotation):

```
public class ProgressBarPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.<ViewManager>singletonList(
            new ProgressBarViewManager()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `@override` annotation in line19 method from ProgressBarPackage.java. It should be pops error again for other methods. If it pops error for other method, you need to remove `@override` from all of those methods as well

Answer (score 1):

ProgressBarPackage does not extend a superclass; therefore, it cannot override methods. If you delete the annotations, it may work.